# tag-it: save to database?

Tags: php, ajax, tag-it

I'm using [Tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/), and I'm trying to save the added tags into my database (with ajax and php). This is what I got:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myTags").tagit({
        afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
                        $.get("/addtag.php", { tag_content: "TAG_CONTENT" });
                        }
    });
});
```

addtag.php:

```
$TAG_CONTENT = $_GET["tag_content"];
mysql_connect("xxx", "xxx", "xxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO test (tags) VALUES ('%s');", $TAG_CONTENT);
mysql_query($query);
```

But how can I save the "real" tag? How do I get the value? Right now it, ofc, just saves the string "TAG_CONTENT"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looking for

```
$.get("/addtag.php", { tag_content: ui.tag });
```

or

```
$.get("/addtag.php", { tag_content: ui.tagLabel });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but maybe there are more people with this problem.

I was facing the same problem few minutes ago and and I was trying to use this with multiple input fields. So, I solved with the below approach:

```js
function updateTags(answerId, data) {
    $.post("/api/v1/tags/ + answerId + "/tags", data, function(data, status) {
    });
}

$(".list-tags").tagit({
    fieldName: 'tags[]',
    placeholderText: 'Add Tag',
    afterTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        if(! ui.duringInitialization) {
            var form = $(this).parent();
            var answerId = $(form).attr('data-id');
            updateTags(answerId, $(form).serialize()); 
        }

    },
    afterTagRemoved: function(event, ui) {
        var form = $(this).parent();
        var answerId = $(form).attr('data-id');
        updateTags(answerId, $(form).serialize()); 
    }
});
```

```html
<form class="form-tags" data-id="{{myObject.id}}">
  <ul class="list-tags"></ul>
</form>
```